# meta_query where value is equal to given value

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, post-meta

I currently have this custom query which I am trying to filter the product (paintings) by artist.

```
                    $artistID = $_GET['artist_id'];

                    $args = array(
                      'post_type' => 'product',
                      'meta_query'     => array(
                        array(
                          'key'     => 'artist',
                          'value'   => $artistID
                        ) 
                      )
                    );

                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

It isn't working at the moment...

When I run

```
var_dump(get_post_meta(get_the_ID()));
```

It outputs the following (interested in the artist key)... Can anyone help me write a query to only get the posts with the given value please? It's worth noting that the meta_data of the post is coming from advanced custom fields relationship field which is a Post Object.

```
array(41) {
      ["_edit_lock"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(12) "1473170740:7"
      }
      ["_edit_last"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "7"
      }
      ["_thumbnail_id"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "279"
      }
      ["_product_attributes"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(510) "a:3:{s:12:"pa_hang-type";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:12:"pa_hang-type";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"0";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:18:"pa_limited-edition";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:18:"pa_limited-edition";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"1";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}s:7:"pa_size";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:7:"pa_size";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"3";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}}"
      }
      ["_visibility"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(7) "visible"
      }
      ["_stock_status"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(7) "instock"
      }
      ["total_sales"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "0"
      }
      ["_downloadable"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(2) "no"
      }
      ["_virtual"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(2) "no"
      }
      ["_tax_status"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(7) "taxable"
      }
      ["_tax_class"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      ["_purchase_note"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      ["_featured"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(2) "no"
      }
      ["_weight"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      ["_length"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      ["_width"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      ["_height"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      ["_sku"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      ["_regular_price"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(2) "60"
      }
      ["_sale_price"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      ["_sale_price_dates_from"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      ["_sale_price_dates_to"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      ["_price"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(2) "60"
      }
      ["_sold_individually"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      ["_manage_stock"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(2) "no"
      }
      ["_backorders"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(2) "no"
      }
      ["_stock"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      ["_upsell_ids"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(6) "a:0:{}"
      }
      ["_crosssell_ids"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(6) "a:0:{}"
      }
      ["_product_version"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(5) "2.6.4"
      }
      ["_product_image_gallery"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "279"
      }
      ["artist"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "168"
      }
      ["_artist"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(19) "field_57c6d280c7a91"
      }
      ["_yoast_wpseo_primary_product_cat"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(2) "32"
      }
      ["_yoast_wpseo_focuskw_text_input"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(23) "Worker Bee Wildlife Art"
      }
      ["_yoast_wpseo_focuskw"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(23) "Worker Bee Wildlife Art"
      }
      ["_yoast_wpseo_linkdex"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(2) "22"
      }
      ["_yoast_wpseo_content_score"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(2) "30"
      }
      ["_wc_rating_count"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(6) "a:0:{}"
      }
      ["_wc_average_rating"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "0"
      }
      ["_a3_dgallery"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "279"
      }
    }
```

Please also see the var_dump($loop) output as well.

```
                object(WP_Query)#8961 (49) {
  ["query"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["post_type"]=>
    string(7) "product"
    ["meta_query"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(6) "artist"
        ["value"]=>
        string(3) "174"
      }
    }
  }
  ["query_vars"]=>
  array(65) {
    ["post_type"]=>
    string(7) "product"
    ["meta_query"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(6) "artist"
        ["value"]=>
        string(3) "174"
      }
    }
    ["error"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["m"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["p"]=>
    int(0)
    ["post_parent"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["subpost"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["subpost_id"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["attachment"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["attachment_id"]=>
    int(0)
    ["name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["static"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["pagename"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["page_id"]=>
    int(0)
    ["second"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["minute"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["hour"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["day"]=>
    int(0)
    ["monthnum"]=>
    int(0)
    ["year"]=>
    int(0)
    ["w"]=>
    int(0)
    ["category_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tag"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["cat"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tag_id"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["feed"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tb"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["paged"]=>
    int(0)
    ["meta_key"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["meta_value"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["preview"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["s"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["sentence"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["title"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["fields"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["menu_order"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["embed"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["category__in"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["category__not_in"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["category__and"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["post__in"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["post__not_in"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["post_name__in"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["tag__in"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["tag__not_in"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["tag__and"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["tag_slug__in"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["tag_slug__and"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["post_parent__in"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["post_parent__not_in"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["author__in"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["author__not_in"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["ignore_sticky_posts"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["suppress_filters"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["cache_results"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["update_post_term_cache"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["lazy_load_term_meta"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["update_post_meta_cache"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["posts_per_page"]=>
    int(8)
    ["nopaging"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["comments_per_page"]=>
    string(2) "50"
    ["no_found_rows"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["order"]=>
    string(4) "DESC"
  }
  ["tax_query"]=>
  object(WP_Tax_Query)#8958 (6) {
    ["queries"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["relation"]=>
    string(3) "AND"
    ["table_aliases":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["queried_terms"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["primary_table"]=>
    string(10) "wp_2_posts"
    ["primary_id_column"]=>
    string(2) "ID"
  }
  ["meta_query"]=>
  object(WP_Meta_Query)#8959 (9) {
    ["queries"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(6) "artist"
        ["value"]=>
        string(3) "174"
      }
      ["relation"]=>
      string(2) "OR"
    }
    ["relation"]=>
    string(3) "AND"
    ["meta_table"]=>
    string(13) "wp_2_postmeta"
    ["meta_id_column"]=>
    string(7) "post_id"
    ["primary_table"]=>
    string(10) "wp_2_posts"
    ["primary_id_column"]=>
    string(2) "ID"
    ["table_aliases":protected]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(13) "wp_2_postmeta"
    }
    ["clauses":protected]=>
    array(1) {
      ["wp_2_postmeta"]=>
      array(5) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(6) "artist"
        ["value"]=>
        string(3) "174"
        ["compare"]=>
        string(1) "="
        ["alias"]=>
        string(13) "wp_2_postmeta"
        ["cast"]=>
        string(4) "CHAR"
      }
    }
    ["has_or_relation":protected]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  ["date_query"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["request"]=>
  string(453) "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_2_posts.ID FROM wp_2_posts  INNER JOIN wp_2_postmeta ON ( wp_2_posts.ID = wp_2_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  ( wp_2_postmeta.meta_key = 'artist' AND wp_2_postmeta.meta_value = '174' )
) AND wp_2_posts.post_type = 'product' AND (wp_2_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_2_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_2_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_2_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_2_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 8"
  ["posts"]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    object(WP_Post)#8957 (24) {
      ["ID"]=>
      int(297)
      ["post_author"]=>
      string(1) "7"
      ["post_date"]=>
      string(19) "2016-09-07 15:23:42"
      ["post_date_gmt"]=>
      string(19) "2016-09-07 14:23:42"
      ["post_content"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_title"]=>
      string(5) "Alone"
      ["post_excerpt"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_status"]=>
      string(7) "publish"
      ["comment_status"]=>
      string(4) "open"
      ["ping_status"]=>
      string(6) "closed"
      ["post_password"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_name"]=>
      string(5) "alone"
      ["to_ping"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["pinged"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_modified"]=>
      string(19) "2016-09-07 15:23:42"
      ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
      string(19) "2016-09-07 14:23:42"
      ["post_content_filtered"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_parent"]=>
      int(0)
      ["guid"]=>
      string(55) "http://shop.localhost.com/?post_type=product&p=297"
      ["menu_order"]=>
      int(0)
      ["post_type"]=>
      string(7) "product"
      ["post_mime_type"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["comment_count"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["filter"]=>
      string(3) "raw"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(WP_Post)#8956 (24) {
      ["ID"]=>
      int(295)
      ["post_author"]=>
      string(1) "7"
      ["post_date"]=>
      string(19) "2016-09-07 09:36:34"
      ["post_date_gmt"]=>
      string(19) "2016-09-07 08:36:34"
      ["post_content"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_title"]=>
      string(11) "Reef Glider"
      ["post_excerpt"]=>
      string(69) "This is a description of the Product. It does not need to be entered."
      ["post_status"]=>
      string(7) "publish"
      ["comment_status"]=>
      string(4) "open"
      ["ping_status"]=>
      string(6) "closed"
      ["post_password"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_name"]=>
      string(11) "reef-glider"
      ["to_ping"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["pinged"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_modified"]=>
      string(19) "2016-09-19 12:06:24"
      ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
      string(19) "2016-09-19 11:06:24"
      ["post_content_filtered"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_parent"]=>
      int(0)
      ["guid"]=>
      string(55) "http://shop.localhost.com/?post_type=product&p=295"
      ["menu_order"]=>
      int(0)
      ["post_type"]=>
      string(7) "product"
      ["post_mime_type"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["comment_count"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["filter"]=>
      string(3) "raw"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(WP_Post)#8955 (24) {
      ["ID"]=>
      int(293)
      ["post_author"]=>
      string(1) "7"
      ["post_date"]=>
      string(19) "2016-09-07 09:33:30"
      ["post_date_gmt"]=>
      string(19) "2016-09-07 08:33:30"
      ["post_content"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_title"]=>
      string(16) "Heart of The Sea"
      ["post_excerpt"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_status"]=>
      string(7) "publish"
      ["comment_status"]=>
      string(4) "open"
      ["ping_status"]=>
      string(6) "closed"
      ["post_password"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_name"]=>
      string(16) "heart-of-the-sea"
      ["to_ping"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["pinged"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_modified"]=>
      string(19) "2016-09-19 16:48:53"
      ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
      string(19) "2016-09-19 15:48:53"
      ["post_content_filtered"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_parent"]=>
      int(0)
      ["guid"]=>
      string(55) "http://shop.localhost.com/?post_type=product&p=293"
      ["menu_order"]=>
      int(0)
      ["post_type"]=>
      string(7) "product"
      ["post_mime_type"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["comment_count"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["filter"]=>
      string(3) "raw"
    }
    [3]=>
    object(WP_Post)#8954 (24) {
      ["ID"]=>
      int(291)
      ["post_author"]=>
      string(1) "7"
      ["post_date"]=>
      string(19) "2016-09-06 16:46:38"
      ["post_date_gmt"]=>
      string(19) "2016-09-06 15:46:38"
      ["post_content"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_title"]=>
      string(6) "Escape"
      ["post_excerpt"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_status"]=>
      string(7) "publish"
      ["comment_status"]=>
      string(4) "open"
      ["ping_status"]=>
      string(6) "closed"
      ["post_password"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_name"]=>
      string(6) "escape"
      ["to_ping"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["pinged"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_modified"]=>
      string(19) "2016-09-06 16:46:38"
      ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
      string(19) "2016-09-06 15:46:38"
      ["post_content_filtered"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["post_parent"]=>
      int(0)
      ["guid"]=>
      string(55) "http://shop.localhost.com/?post_type=product&p=291"
      ["menu_order"]=>
      int(0)
      ["post_type"]=>
      string(7) "product"
      ["post_mime_type"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["comment_count"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["filter"]=>
      string(3) "raw"
    }
    [4]=>
    object(WP_Post)#8772 (24) {
      ["ID"]=>
      int(289)
      ["post_author"]=>
      string(1) "7"
      ["post_date"]=>
      string(19) "2016-09-06 16:02:57"
      ["post_date_gmt"]=>
      s…
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there -- you just need to add the comparison to your meta query:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'meta_query'     => array(
    array(
      'key'     => 'artist',
      'value'   => $artistID,
      'compare' => '='
    ) 
  )
);
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Remember to filter `$artistID` before accepting it in your query!

Comment: Unfortunately it's still showing all of them! No idea as to why! Any other thoughts? :/

Comment: Thomas, does it make any difference if you add relation => 'AND' in the meta_query array?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not Ahmed!

Comment: Are you using the `$loop` object variable to set up your products loop? i.e. `if ($loop->have_posts()) : while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); endwhile; endif;`? Your `WP_Query` object looks fine, and your SQL seems OK too

Comment: Yeah I'm using the loop as you explained in the above!

Comment: It's worth noting that the meta_data of the post is coming from advanced custom fields relationship field, which apparently...

_The relationship field saves it’s data as a serialized array. If you are not familiar with this format, please look up the stored value in your database. It will look something_

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/

Comment: Did you try the compare operator LIKE instead of = ?

Comment: I'm confused because in the var dump `var_dump(get_post_meta(get_the_ID()));`
it outputs
`array(
      ["artist"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "168"
      }
)` which doesn't look serialized!?

Comment: @AhmedMahdi I have indeed tried that and still nothing. :(

Comment: Ahhh.. you're using ACF. Then you need to get the actual ACF custom field key which is hashed -- edit the custom field and in screen options click 'field key'. This is the thing that you need to search for in the meta_query

Comment: Where abouts do I click 'field key'? I can't find it anywhere in the admin panel

Comment: @Thomas_Hoadley it's under the 'Screen options' tab at the top right of the admin screen -- you need to be editing a custom field group

Comment: @FaCE They've all been ticked. Hmmm

Answer (score 1):

firstly in term of security you need to filter the artist_id variable before accepting it, secondly you should run the var_dump(get_post_meta(get_the_ID())) inside the query loop, try the following code it should work for you :

```
<?php 
    $artistID = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'artist_id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $args = array(
        //Type & Status Parameters
        'post_type'   => 'product',
        //Order & Orderby Parameters
        'order'               => 'DESC',
        'orderby'             => 'date',

        //Pagination Parameters
        'posts_per_page'         => -1,
        //Custom Field Parameters
        'meta_key'       => 'artist',
        'meta_value'     => $artistID,
        'meta_compare'   => '=',

    );

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        global $post;
        var_dump(get_post_meta($post->ID);
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Thank you for your answer Amine. I have tried implementing it however it did not work.